# Script to get an url and place it in a Google form

Tags: google-forms, google-sites

I'm developing a google site where I have a google form. If I click the button a new tab is opened with a google form. One of the parameter to write in it is the current url. Can I create a script that takes the current URL and write it in the google form?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can programatically edit and change a Form ***before*** it is opened, but you can not dynamically change a Form while it's open in view (input) mode.  If you want to edit the Form, milliseconds before it's opened, you can do that with a script, but if have multiple users opening the Form at the same time, you could run into a problem with not getting the correct changes to the correct user.

Comment: @SandyGood Thanks Sandy. Can you help me with the scripts?. I wrote it but it doesn't work. Do you want me to show you my code?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with your code.  You should always post code with your question.  If you do most of the work, someone can probably give advice, or point out mistakes.  It's a lot easier to help if you post code.  But I can't and won't promise anything.